# call to collectgarbage('count') increases memory usage in lua

Tags: memory, lua, profiling, torch

I am a beginner to lua.  I am trying to profile the memory usage of my application.  When I call collectgarbage('count') repeatedly from lua REPL, the value returned keeps on increasing.

```
th> collectgarbage()
0
                                                                      [0.0018s]
th> collectgarbage('count')
856.8408203125
                                                                      [0.0001s]
th> collectgarbage('count')
858.669921875
                                                                      [0.0001s]
th> collectgarbage('count')
860.345703125
                                                                      [0.0000s]
th> collectgarbage('count')
862.171875
                                                                      [0.0000s]
```

Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: IMO, `collectgarbage('count')` doesn't allocate memory from heap, but converting a number to string and printing it to stdout surely does.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there anyway we can verify that this is the reason for additional memory usage?

Comment: `print(collectgarbage('count'),collectgarbage('count'))` prints two equal values.  Or you can type this in REPL: `th> collectgarbage('count'),collectgarbage('count')`

Comment: Compiling a Lua chunk also allocates memory. And that happens every time you execute code on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nicol Bolas and @egor skriptunoff said above,

This is because compiling a lua code allocates memory and also due to string conversion.